# Что такое "авто-" — приставка или корень?

Tags: морфемика

Как трактовать морфему *авто* в слове:

> автовокзал

Как приставку или как корень? Здравый смысл подсказывает, что это корень, т.к. имеется в виду *автомобильный вокзал*.

Тогда что делать со словами:

> автоподача, автопортрет

Тут уже морфема *авто* играет вспомогательную роль и больше походит на приставку. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: @ДеNiZz, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Здесь "авто-" является одним из корней при образовании сложного слова.

1. В слове "автовокзал" (автомобильный вокзал) основа первого исходного слова "автомобильный" (самоходный) сокращена до его первого корня "авто-".
2. В сложном слове автопортрет корень "авто-" несёт смысл русского "сам-о-"("самоизображение").
3. При образовании сложного слова "автоподача" основа первого исходного слова "автоматическая" сокращена до корня "авто-", который и в конечном слове сохраняет смысл русского "сам-о".